# Issues with \rowcolors

Tags: tables, color

I'm having problems in my latex code. I would like to alternate the color of my rows, but everytime I compile it, I get a strange effect. This is my code:

```
    \begin{center}
    \rowcolors{1}{black!10}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{s{3cm}*{2}{|s{2cm}}|s{3cm}|s{2cm}}
      \firsthline
      \multicolumn{1}{s{3cm}}{Misure di $l_m$\\($cm$)} & \multicolumn{1}{s{2cm}}{$l_m$\\($\pm 0.1\:cm$)} & \multicolumn{1}{s{2cm}}{$l_f$\\($\pm 0.1\:cm$)} & \multicolumn{1}{s{3cm}}{Misure di $T$\\($s$)} & \multicolumn{1}{s{2cm}}{$T$\\($\pm 0.01\:s$)} \tabularnewline \hline
      130.9 / 130.9  131.1 / 131.0  131.1 & 131.0 & 133.6 & 2.324 / 2.320  2.317 / 2.324  2.320 & 2.32 \tabularnewline \hline
      110.9 / 111.0  110.8 / 110.9  110.9 & 110.9 & 113.5 & 2.123 / 2.121  2.134 / 2.137  2.131 & 2.13 \tabularnewline \hline
      91.4 / 91.6  91.5 / 91.6  91.5 & 91.5 & 94.1 & 1.948 / 1.930  1.936 / 1.931  1.949 & 1.94 \tabularnewline \hline
      73.2 / 73.2  73.2 / 73.1  73.2 & 73.2 & 75.8 & 1.720 / 1.742  1.725 / 1.735  1.735 & 1.73 \tabularnewline \hline
      47.4 / 47.4  47.4 / 47.3  47.3 & 47.4 & 50.1 & 1.406 / 1.407  1.413 / 1.404  1.411 & 1.41 \tabularnewline \hline
      25.5 / 25.4  25.5 / 25.5  25.4 & 25.5 & 28.0 & 1.047 / 1.035  1.053 / 1.060  1.035 & 1.05 \tabularnewline
      \lasthline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
```

[image: Compiled code]

This is a short compilable test:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[left=25mm, right=25mm, headheight=32pt, bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{s}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{black!10}{white}
\begin{tabular}{s{3cm}*{2}{|s{2cm}}|s{3cm}|s{2cm}}
  \firsthline
  \multicolumn{1}{s{3cm}}{Misure di $l_m$\\($cm$)} & \multicolumn{1}{s{2cm}}{$l_m$\\($\pm 0.1\:cm$)} & \multicolumn{1}{s{2cm}}{$l_f$\\($\pm 0.1\:cm$)} & \multicolumn{1}{s{3cm}}{Misure di $T$\\($s$)} & \multicolumn{1}{s{2cm}}{$T$\\($\pm 0.01\:s$)} \tabularnewline \hline
  130.9 / 130.9  131.1 / 131.0  131.1 & 131.0 & 133.6 & 2.324 / 2.320  2.317 / 2.324  2.320 & 2.32 \tabularnewline \hline
  110.9 / 111.0  110.8 / 110.9  110.9 & 110.9 & 113.5 & 2.123 / 2.121  2.134 / 2.137  2.131 & 2.13 \tabularnewline \hline
  91.4 / 91.6  91.5 / 91.6  91.5 & 91.5 & 94.1 & 1.948 / 1.930  1.936 / 1.931  1.949 & 1.94 \tabularnewline \hline
  73.2 / 73.2  73.2 / 73.1  73.2 & 73.2 & 75.8 & 1.720 / 1.742  1.725 / 1.735  1.735 & 1.73 \tabularnewline \hline
  47.4 / 47.4  47.4 / 47.3  47.3 & 47.4 & 50.1 & 1.406 / 1.407  1.413 / 1.404  1.411 & 1.41 \tabularnewline \hline
  25.5 / 25.4  25.5 / 25.5  25.4 & 25.5 & 28.0 & 1.047 / 1.035  1.053 / 1.060  1.035 & 1.05 \tabularnewline
  \lasthline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: You might also want to read https://texdoc.org/serve/booktabs.pdf/0 If you would remove vertical lines and colours your table might look more professional and you will avoid your current problems.

Comment: Ok, I wrote a short code that shows the same issue

Answer (score 3):

Just don't use `\firsthline` and `\lasthline`, but `\hline`. And invert the colors.

Anyway, the typesetting is really awful…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{s}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\rowcolors{1}{white}{black!10}

\begin{tabular}{
  s{2cm}|
  s{2cm}|
  s{2cm}|
  s{2cm}|
  s{2cm}
}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{s{2cm}}{Misure di $l_m$\\(\unit{cm})} &
\multicolumn{1}{s{2cm}}{$l_m$\\(\qty{\pm 0.1}{cm})} &
\multicolumn{1}{s{2cm}}{$l_f$\\(\qty{\pm 0.1}{cm})} &
\multicolumn{1}{s{2cm}}{Misure di $T$\\(\unit{s})} &
\multicolumn{1}{s{2cm}}{$T$\\(\qty{\pm 0.01}{s})} \tabularnewline
\hline
130.9 / 130.9  131.1 / 131.0  131.1 & 131.0 & 133.6 & 2.324 / 2.320  2.317 / 2.324  2.320 & 2.32 \tabularnewline \hline
110.9 / 111.0  110.8 / 110.9  110.9 & 110.9 & 113.5 & 2.123 / 2.121  2.134 / 2.137  2.131 & 2.13 \tabularnewline \hline
91.4 / 91.6  91.5 / 91.6  91.5 & 91.5 & 94.1 & 1.948 / 1.930  1.936 / 1.931  1.949 & 1.94 \tabularnewline \hline
73.2 / 73.2  73.2 / 73.1  73.2 & 73.2 & 75.8 & 1.720 / 1.742  1.725 / 1.735  1.735 & 1.73 \tabularnewline \hline
47.4 / 47.4  47.4 / 47.3  47.3 & 47.4 & 50.1 & 1.406 / 1.407  1.413 / 1.404  1.411 & 1.41 \tabularnewline \hline
25.5 / 25.4  25.5 / 25.5  25.4 & 25.5 & 28.0 & 1.047 / 1.035  1.053 / 1.060  1.035 & 1.05 \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I fixed the width to be all 2cm, so as to reproduce your picture.
Note also the usage of `\unit` and `\qty` from `siunitx`: units should ***always*** be in upright type and `$cm$` would be wrong anyway.

[image]

Alternatively, without vertical rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{s}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\rowcolors{1}{white}{black!10}

\begin{tabular}{
  s{2cm}
  s{2cm}
  s{2cm}
  s{2cm}
  s{2cm}
}
\toprule
Misure di $l_m$\\(\unit{cm}) &
$l_m$\\(\qty{\pm 0.1}{cm}) &
$l_f$\\(\qty{\pm 0.1}{cm}) &
Misure di $T$\\(\unit{s}) &
$T$\\(\qty{\pm 0.01}{s}) \tabularnewline
\midrule
\addlinespace[-0.05\belowrulesep]
130.9 / 130.9  131.1 / 131.0  131.1 & 131.0 & 133.6 & 2.324 / 2.320  2.317 / 2.324  2.320 & 2.32 \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
110.9 / 111.0  110.8 / 110.9  110.9 & 110.9 & 113.5 & 2.123 / 2.121  2.134 / 2.137  2.131 & 2.13 \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
91.4 / 91.6  91.5 / 91.6  91.5 & 91.5 & 94.1 & 1.948 / 1.930  1.936 / 1.931  1.949 & 1.94 \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
73.2 / 73.2  73.2 / 73.1  73.2 & 73.2 & 75.8 & 1.720 / 1.742  1.725 / 1.735  1.735 & 1.73 \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
47.4 / 47.4  47.4 / 47.3  47.3 & 47.4 & 50.1 & 1.406 / 1.407  1.413 / 1.404  1.411 & 1.41 \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
25.5 / 25.4  25.5 / 25.5  25.4 & 25.5 & 28.0 & 1.047 / 1.035  1.053 / 1.060  1.035 & 1.05 \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And without colored bands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{s}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  s{2cm}
  s{2cm}
  s{2cm}
  s{2cm}
  s{2cm}
  @{}
}
\toprule
Misure di $l_m$\\(\unit{cm}) &
$l_m$\\(\qty{\pm 0.1}{cm}) &
$l_f$\\(\qty{\pm 0.1}{cm}) &
Misure di $T$\\(\unit{s}) &
$T$\\(\qty{\pm 0.01}{s}) \tabularnewline
\midrule
130.9 / 130.9  131.1 / 131.0  131.1 & 131.0 & 133.6 & 2.324 / 2.320  2.317 / 2.324  2.320 & 2.32 \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
110.9 / 111.0  110.8 / 110.9  110.9 & 110.9 & 113.5 & 2.123 / 2.121  2.134 / 2.137  2.131 & 2.13 \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
91.4 / 91.6  91.5 / 91.6  91.5 & 91.5 & 94.1 & 1.948 / 1.930  1.936 / 1.931  1.949 & 1.94 \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
73.2 / 73.2  73.2 / 73.1  73.2 & 73.2 & 75.8 & 1.720 / 1.742  1.725 / 1.735  1.735 & 1.73 \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
47.4 / 47.4  47.4 / 47.3  47.3 & 47.4 & 50.1 & 1.406 / 1.407  1.413 / 1.404  1.411 & 1.41 \tabularnewline
\addlinespace
25.5 / 25.4  25.5 / 25.5  25.4 & 25.5 & 28.0 & 1.047 / 1.035  1.053 / 1.060  1.035 & 1.05 \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

I would rather go with the [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray?lang=en) package.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={Q[c,m,6em]Q[c,m,4.5em]Q[c,m,4.5em]Q[c,m,6em]Q[c,m,4.5em]},
        row{odd}={bg=white},
        row{even}={bg=black!10},
        vline{2-Y} = {1}{0.4pt,white},       % vertical lines of top row
        vline{2-Y} = {2-Z}{0.4pt,black},     % vertical lines of 2nd to last row
        hline{3-Y} = {0.4pt,black, solid},   % thin horizontal lines
        hline{1,2,Z} = {0.8pt,black, solid}, % thick horizontal lines
    }
        Misure di $l_m$ ($cm$)              & $l_m$ ($\pm 0.1\:cm$) & $l_f$ ($\pm 0.1\:cm$) & Misure di $T$ ($s$)                 & $T$ ($\pm 0.01\:s$) \\
        130.9 / 130.9  131.1 / 131.0  131.1 & 131.0                 & 133.6                 & 2.324 / 2.320  2.317 / 2.324  2.320 & 2.32                \\
        110.9 / 111.0  110.8 / 110.9  110.9 & 110.9                 & 113.5                 & 2.123 / 2.121  2.134 / 2.137  2.131 & 2.13                \\
        91.4 / 91.6  91.5 / 91.6  91.5      & 91.5                  & 94.1                  & 1.948 / 1.930  1.936 / 1.931  1.949 & 1.94                \\
        73.2 / 73.2  73.2 / 73.1  73.2      & 73.2                  & 75.8                  & 1.720 / 1.742  1.725 / 1.735  1.735 & 1.73                \\
        47.4 / 47.4  47.4 / 47.3  47.3      & 47.4                  & 50.1                  & 1.406 / 1.407  1.413 / 1.404  1.411 & 1.41                \\
        25.5 / 25.4  25.5 / 25.5  25.4      & 25.5                  & 28.0                  & 1.047 / 1.035  1.053 / 1.060  1.035 & 1.05                \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to create that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. The output will be perfect in all PDF viewers: the rules won't seem to disappear and you won't see thin white lines in the first row.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[left=25mm, right=25mm, headheight=32pt, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=3pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{m[c]{3cm} | m[c]{2cm} | m[c]{2cm} | m[c]{3cm} | m[c]{2cm}}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{1}{black!10}{white}
\Body
  \toprule
  \Block{1-*}{} % in order to prevent vertical rules in that row
  \Block{}{Misure di $l_m$\\($cm$)} & \Block{}{$l_m$\\($\pm 0.1\:cm$)} & \Block{}{$l_f$\\($\pm 0.1\:cm$)} & \Block{}{Misure di $T$\\($s$)} & \Block{}{$T$\\($\pm 0.01\:s$)} \\ \Hline
  130.9 / 130.9  131.1 / 131.0  131.1 & 131.0 & 133.6 & 2.324 / 2.320  2.317 / 2.324  2.320 & 2.32 \\ \Hline
  110.9 / 111.0  110.8 / 110.9  110.9 & 110.9 & 113.5 & 2.123 / 2.121  2.134 / 2.137  2.131 & 2.13 \\ \Hline
  91.4 / 91.6  91.5 / 91.6  91.5 & 91.5 & 94.1 & 1.948 / 1.930  1.936 / 1.931  1.949 & 1.94 \\ \Hline
  73.2 / 73.2  73.2 / 73.1  73.2 & 73.2 & 75.8 & 1.720 / 1.742  1.725 / 1.735  1.735 & 1.73 \\ \Hline
  47.4 / 47.4  47.4 / 47.3  47.3 & 47.4 & 50.1 & 1.406 / 1.407  1.413 / 1.404  1.411 & 1.41 \\ \Hline
  25.5 / 25.4  25.5 / 25.5  25.4 & 25.5 & 28.0 & 1.047 / 1.035  1.053 / 1.060  1.035 & 1.05 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't use any special alignment for the table, it seems unnecessary to use `\first/\lasthline`. As a nice side effect, this also avoids the problems you experience:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[left=25mm, right=25mm, headheight=32pt, bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{s}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{black!10}{white}
\begin{tabular}{s{3cm}*{2}{|s{2cm}}|s{3cm}|s{2cm}}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{s{3cm}}{Misure di $l_m$\\(cm)} & \multicolumn{1}{s{2cm}}{$l_m$\\($\pm 0.1\:$cm)} & \multicolumn{1}{s{2cm}}{$l_f$\\($\pm 0.1\:$cm)} & \multicolumn{1}{s{3cm}}{Misure di $T$\\(s)} & \multicolumn{1}{s{2cm}}{$T$\\($\pm 0.01\:$s)} \tabularnewline \hline
  130.9 / 130.9  131.1 / 131.0  131.1 & 131.0 & 133.6 & 2.324 / 2.320  2.317 / 2.324  2.320 & 2.32 \tabularnewline \hline
  110.9 / 111.0  110.8 / 110.9  110.9 & 110.9 & 113.5 & 2.123 / 2.121  2.134 / 2.137  2.131 & 2.13 \tabularnewline \hline
  91.4 / 91.6  91.5 / 91.6  91.5 & 91.5 & 94.1 & 1.948 / 1.930  1.936 / 1.931  1.949 & 1.94 \tabularnewline \hline
  73.2 / 73.2  73.2 / 73.1  73.2 & 73.2 & 75.8 & 1.720 / 1.742  1.725 / 1.735  1.735 & 1.73 \tabularnewline \hline
  47.4 / 47.4  47.4 / 47.3  47.3 & 47.4 & 50.1 & 1.406 / 1.407  1.413 / 1.404  1.411 & 1.41 \tabularnewline \hline
  25.5 / 25.4  25.5 / 25.5  25.4 & 25.5 & 28.0 & 1.047 / 1.035  1.053 / 1.060  1.035 & 1.05 \tabularnewline
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]